# Counterpart of gcc's -save-temps option in make

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm studying compiling and linking processes.

Running `gcc` with `-save-temps` option, I can get temporary files generated during building process.

I think there must be a counterpart of it in make also.

Anybody know the way?

Comment: You want to pass `-save-temps` to `gcc` when it is run by make? Or you want a similar "don't delete intermediate files" for make itself (for files that make normally deletes as unnecessary intermediate files)?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I want to look at all temporary files for studying. Is there a way to pass `-save-temps` to `gcc`?

Comment: Yes. How depends on the makefile. If it uses the built-in rules correctly then something like `make CFLAGS=-save-temps` might work.

Comment: It does not work for me. Actually my Makefile was generated by CMake, and I think there is some command for cleaning temporary files in my Makefile.

Comment: That's possible. Though I would think unlikely for `gcc` intermediate files. It is more likely that cmake isn't using the built-in rules (since cmake likes to hard-code everything for some reason) and you'll just need to find out what variable make *does* use when compiling so you can add `-save-temps` to it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding below set to CMakeList.txt does the job ,

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --save-temps")
```